# Illegal character in query android

Tags: android

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 98: http://www.example.com&gmap=25.2600007|55.31000
```

I am trying to add the GoogleMap latitude and longitude to server, but I am getting Illegal character exception.
I need to pass pipe symbol in between latitude and longitude

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            jsonResponseString = jsonParser.makeHttpRequestForAnnouncement(
                    "http:/example.com"&gmap=" + latlongString,
                    "POST");
        } catch (Exception e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done


    }
```

and `latlongString = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude() + "|"
                + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));`

Comment: post code and recheck the encoding of your string

Answer (score 1):

In urls the pipe char `|` should be encoded as `%7C`

So your example url:

```
http://www.example.com&gmap=25.2600007|55.31000
```

should be:

```
http://www.example.com&gmap=25.2600007%7C55.31000
```

also you probably wanted `&` to be `?` since it is the first url parameter.

==> Update: If you got this wrong encoded url from some api then you could fix it with doing  a string replace, like for example:

```
String urlStr = "http://www.example.com&gmap=25.2600007|55.31000";
String fixedUrlStr = urlStr.replace("|", "%7C")
```

Comment: but the api i am using returns invalid parameters.

Comment: @LeiLeyba see the updated answer, you could try replacing the invalid chars manually in your code.

Comment: thanks. but i figured out that my problem was that I needed to use Get method. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There is a single '/' after http:
Needs to be '//'